# frame-processor/unavailable: Frame Processors are not enabled. React Native

Tags: react-native, barcode-scanner, react-native-vision-camera

```
"react-native": "0.71.6",
"react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.4",
"react-native-vision-camera": "^2.16.2",
"vision-camera-code-scanner": "^0.2.0"
"react-native-hole-view": "^2.2.0",
"@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.4.0",
"@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.4.0",
```

babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
    presets: ['module:metro-react-native-babel-preset'],
    plugins: [
        [
            'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
            { globals: ['__scanCodes'] }
        ],
        [
            "module:react-native-dotenv", 
            {
                "envName": "APP_ENV",
                "moduleName": "@env",
                "path": ".env",
                "safe": false,
                "allowUndefined": true,
                "verbose": false
            }
        ]
    ]
};
```

I was using vision-camera 2.15.4, but xcode 15 is not compatible with it. So I upgrade it to 2.16.2. Now, "frame-processor/unavailable" error on both android and ios

I have tried with reanimated V3 Vision Camera V3 on React Native 0.73.1,
In which case "Build failed" on android.

"react-native-worklets-core": "^0.2.4",
babel.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  presets: ['module:@react-native/babel-preset'],
  plugins: [
    "react-native-worklets-core/plugin",
    'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
  ],
};
```

Comment: Requires reanimated 3.5+ from 2.16.0 and later.